# Pyinstaller excluding tkinter module when compiling

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm building a project I plan on distributing. The compiled dist file works fine on my computer, but when I send it to others it fails. I've noticed in the build that it excludes 'tkinter' module, which is the GUI of the project. I've tried every option out there to `-import tkinter` `--hidden-import=tkinter` literally everything, on multiple versions of python, and with pyinstaller installed with both pip and pip3. I've reached the end of the universe :P and tkinter still won't include in the build.

PLEEEEASE HEEEEEELLLP!

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe that you seen it in cmd while processing the code. As far as I am concerned, the pyinstaller automatically includes **tkinter**... That said there's no need to include it separately (by the way: *--hidden-import* isn't appropriate for modules defined in classical way - *import tkinter*). Have you tried running the pyinstaller script simply without any including options?

2nd option:
Try using cx_freeze as explained here [cx_freeze tutorial](https://youtu.be/GSoOwSqTSrs). It's a bit more coding, but it may work better for you

Comment: Will cx_freeze create a onefile? And yes I saw in the build it’s excluding.

Comment: No, but you can pack folder you get using InstallForge software to classic InstallShield Wizard (which is in my opinion the best way). I have also seen that tkinter is excluded while "pyinstalling", but it's probably a bug, because when I launched the .exe from dist folder, it was working

Comment: It will work on your end, but if you try to distribute it crashes on anyone else’s pc. That’s been my experience anyway.

Comment: Hmmm, my experience was different, when the exe was launched on another PC, it also worked... (it didn't at first, tkinter was ok, but I got problems with another packages)

Comment: Brociouschristopher@gmail.com give me an email man. I’d love to get to the bottom of this and if you can help I’ll do what I can in return

Comment: what versions of python and pyinstaller are you using

Comment: Python 3.6.2
Pyinstaller latest :)

Comment: I've tried it on 3.6.2 and 3.7. Latest for pyinstaller is 3.3.1 right?

Comment: That's true, indeed

Comment: In my case the problem was within another module that was also in the code - keyboard...

Comment: would you be open to running it on your pc to see what the cmd prompt is telling you?

Comment: Ok, you can send it to me: martin@topikt.com

Comment: just sent it to you.

Comment: So first of all, as soon as I scan it via antivirus, it pops up approximately 13 rootkits. As this longs, I won't be able to run it on my pc

Comment: Not sure what that means? Still a PC baby over here :P

Comment: Probably that it is detecting some threats

Comment: So what should I do? I've sent it to microsoft (one of the hundreds of builds I've compiled) to have it vetted for malware. It came back fine, but still having issues when distributing.

Comment: So my advice is following: build it using pyinstaller using method which exports one folder -D (instead of onefile). And when you launch exe from dist folder, if something is wrong, pop-up windows should appear telling you what's wrong. I've got nothing more to say

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with pyinstaller excluding Tkinter during build process for a pyinstaller --onefile filename.py build.   My pyinstaller .exe file would run on my system with Python installed, but, not on an independent windows system without Python installed.  Failed to run with a message:

File "Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1819, in __init___tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/lib/tcl8.5 E:/lib/tcl8.5 E:/lib/tcl8.5 E:/library E:/library E:/tcl8.5.15/library E:/tcl8.5.15/library

I tried a few things, however, in the end this worked:
at the top of the .py file, where I do all my imports, I added:

import Tkinter

after this addition, I still see a message that says that Tkinter is excluded during the pysintaller build process, but, the final .exe file runs on an independent machine without Python installed.

hope this helps.  I remain puzzled by the error, which, did not occur in my last distribution 5 months ago.